# HTTP 400 when uploading a file using Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am receiving an HTTP 400 error when attempting to upload a file.

Here is the client code:

**form.jsp**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<c:url value="/upload"/>">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>File to upload:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the method handling the form:

**FormController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
    if (name.contains("/"))
    {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Folder separators not allowed");
        return "redirect:upload";
    }
    if (name.contains("/"))
    {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Relative pathnames not allowed");
        return "redirect:upload";
    }

    if (!file.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File(Application.ROOT + "/" + name)));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
            stream.close();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else
    {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty");
    }

    return "redirect:upload";
}
```

If you need any further information, please comment.

Comment: can you add your configuration code as well?

Comment: Try this - `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>` and then `<form:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`